# put back messages to queue when MDB is suspended weblogic

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, message-driven-bean, suspend

I am using a MDB deployed in Weblogic 10.3.5 consuming messages from a queue.

I'm suspending MDB programmatically but in weblogic console → queue supervision, there are pending messages.

What can I do to put pending messages back into the queue? Or change status to "current messages"?

Comment: You can try to `Force Commit` those tranactions. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13738/manage_msg.htm http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/JMSjmsserverforcetransactioncommittitle.html Also, are you using `AUTO-ACKNOWLEDGE`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `AUTO-ACKNOWLEDGE`, transactions are managed by the container.

Comment: `Force commit` doesn't work, messages change status from pending message to message receive, don't process those message.